# getEvents of undefined in created hook, Vue Kalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Having some trouble with the Vue Kalendar app, followed the instructions to the letter.

Link found here: https://kalendar.altinselimi.com/?ref=madewithvuejs.com

I have the following in my code (had to alter kalendar-vue.css to KalendarVue.css to get that to work, so not sure if I'm missing anything else).

I'm getting a couple of errors at the moment,

Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'getEvents' of undefined"

and

Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'buildWeek' of undefined"

There's not life cycle hooks in the code I'm using so I'm unsure if there's a problem with the component itself, I've been looking around and nobody has mentioned this so it looks as though there's something wrong with my code.

```
<template>
    <kalendar :configuration="calendar_settings" :events="events"/>
</template>

<script>
import {
    Kalendar
} from 'kalendar-vue';
import 'kalendar-vue/dist/KalendarVue.css';

export default {
    components: {
        Kalendar,
    },
    data: () => ({
        events: [],
        calendar_settings: {
            style: 'material_design',
            view_type: 'week',
            cell_height: 20,
            scrollToNow: true,
            current_day: new Date(),
            read_only: false,
            day_starts_at: 0,
            day_ends_at: 24,
            overlap: true,
            hide_dates: ['2019-10-31'], // Spooky
            hide_days: [6],
            past_event_creation: true
        },
        new_appointment: {
            title: null,
            description: null
        }

    }),

    methods: {
        addEvent(popup_data, form_data) {
            let payload = {
                data: {
                    title: this.new_appointment.title,
                    description: this.new_appointment.description,
                },
                from: popup_info.start_time,
                to: popup_info.end_time,
            };

            this.$kalendar.addNewEvent(
                payload,
            );
            this.$kalendar.closePopups();
            this.clearFormData();
        },

        // Remove Event
        removeEvent(kalendarEvent) {
            let day = kalendarEvent.start_time.slice(0, 10);
            this.$kalendar.removeEvent({
                day,
                key: kalendarEvent.key,
                id: kalendarEvent.kalendar_id,
            })
        },
    }

}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The above code is the component I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used this component before but a quick dig into the source finds this:

https://github.com/altinselimi/kalendar/blob/4b1a834b5945e4f61bca6e4e1f333114a0554c8a/src/components/kalendar/kalendar-container.vue#L230

So inside the `created` hook of `kalendar-container.vue` is:

```js
this.$kalendar.getEvents = () => {
```

That ties up with the error message you're seeing.

So the question is, where is `$kalendar` supposed to come from?

Further digging in the source finds it here:

https://github.com/altinselimi/kalendar/blob/4b1a834b5945e4f61bca6e4e1f333114a0554c8a/src/main.js#L6

Why it isn't added within the plugin's `install` function I have no idea but it would seem that you need to add it yourself with:

```js
Vue.prototype.$kalendar = {};
```

Just from a couple of minutes looking at the source code I would be nervous about using this component in my own applications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really informative! I dug through the source like you did but found the code in main.js so I'm a little stumped as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Other than the fact it takes a bit of digging to even attempt to get this to work, is there anything specific that concerns you? Would appreciate any knowledge :)

Comment: @Mtlj1991 1. Strange install process, 2. Passing information around using shared `$kalendar` object on the prototype, 3. Polluting global namespace with `window.kalendarHelpers`, 4. console logging left in, 5. Strange use of `validators` on `props` to check something that's already checked by `type`. 6. `setInterval` used but never cleared. That's just from a quick look and it's more than enough to scare me off.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to avoid this and go back to the drawing board.